# Given an array of integers, from 1 to X find K numbers that sum to N

Tags: python, math, permutation, algebra

Given an array of sorted contiguous integers, from 1 to X find All combination of  K numbers that sum to N? Knowing the numbers can’t be repeated
Ex:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
K =3
N= 8
Output: 
1 2 5
1 3 4
```

Any tips?

Comment: Pro tip: do some research and make an attempt yourself

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `combinations` function from python's `itertools` module.

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> array=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> K=3
>>> N=8
>>> for comb in combinations(array, K):
...   if sum(comb) == N:
...     print(' '.join(list(map(str, comb))))
...
1 2 5
1 3 4
```

Comment: Thanx alot. What is the time complexity in this case ?

Comment: it should be O(C(n,k)) which is equivalent O(n!/k!(n-k)!)

Comment: Generating all combinations and filtering good ones is bad idea for slightly  larger numbers.